# Select rows from a data frame based on values in a vector

Tags: r, subset, r-faq

I have data similar to this:

```
dt <- structure(list(fct = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), X = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("fct", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I want to select rows from this data frame based on the values in the `fct` variable. For example, if I wish to select rows containing either "a" or "c" I can do this:

```
dt[dt$fct == 'a' | dt$fct == 'c', ]
```

which yields

```
1    a 2
3    c 3
5    c 5
7    a 7
9    c 9
10   a 1
12   c 2
14   c 4
```

as expected. But my actual data is more complex and I actually want to select rows based on the values in a vector such as

```
vc <- c('a', 'c')
```

So I tried

```
dt[dt$fct == vc, ]
```

but of course that doesn't work. I know I could code something to loop through the vector and pull out the rows needed and append them to a new dataframe, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way.

So how can I filter/subset my data based on the contents of the vector `vc`?

Comment: try: `dt[dt$fct %in% vc,]`  Basically `==` is for one item and `%in%` is for a vector comparison.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Have a look at `?"%in%"`.

```
dt[dt$fct %in% vc,]
   fct X
1    a 2
3    c 3
5    c 5
7    a 7
9    c 9
10   a 1
12   c 2
14   c 4
```

You could also use `?is.element`:

```
dt[is.element(dt$fct, vc),]
```

Comment: `is.element` is most intuitively understandable.

Answer (score 38):

Similar to above, using `filter` from `dplyr`:

```
filter(df, fct %in% vc)
```

Answer (score 17):

Another option would be to use a keyed `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt, key = 'fct')[J(vc)]  # or: setDT(dt, key = 'fct')[.(vc)]
```

which results in:

```
   fct X
1:   a 2
2:   a 7
3:   a 1
4:   c 3
5:   c 5
6:   c 9
7:   c 2
8:   c 4
```

What this does:

- `setDT(dt, key = 'fct')` transforms the `data.frame` to a `data.table` (which is an enhanced form of a `data.frame`) with the `fct` column set as key.
- Next you can just subset with the `vc` vector with `[J(vc)]`.

NOTE: when the key is a factor/character variable, you can also use `setDT(dt, key = 'fct')[vc]` but that won't work when `vc` is a numeric vector. When `vc` is a numeric vector and is not wrapped in `J()` or `.()`, `vc` will work as a rowindex.

A more detailed explanation of the concept of *keys* and subsetting can be found in the vignette [*Keys and fast binary search based subset*](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html).

An alternative as suggested by @Frank in the comments:

```
setDT(dt)[J(vc), on=.(fct)]
```

---

When `vc` contains values that are not present in `dt`, you'll need to add `nomatch = 0`:

```
setDT(dt, key = 'fct')[J(vc), nomatch = 0]
```

or:

```
setDT(dt)[J(vc), on=.(fct), nomatch = 0]
```

Comment: I coudn't get it work when the vector and the variable in data.table are numeric. Any ideas?

Comment: @GauravSinghal updated the answer, the method in the previous version worked on for character/factor columns; the updated method also works for integer/numeric columns

Comment: @David is there a way to modify this to select only where ftc is NOT in vc?

Comment: @user2017023, yes, e.g. `setDT(dt)[!(vc), on=.(fct)]`