# How to subset dataframe using string values from a list?

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a `data.frame` with several variables for a universe of stocks and I want to create a subset of this data frame that filters the data I have for just the S&P 500 stocks.

I created a list of all the stocks in the S&P 500, and I basically want the program to go through my data frame and copy over all the rows which contain an item from my S&P 500 list. I tried using a for-loop and that crashed my RStudio, so if anyone knows if there's a way I can do this, please let me know!

This code works for just one stock in the S&P500, but I want it to work for all of them. t is what I named my data frame.

```
sp500dataonly <- filter(t, SYMBOL == "AAPL")
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does your list look like?

Comment: s5 = constituents$Symbol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select rows from a data frame based on values in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612235/select-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-values-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a set (technically not a list in R. It is actually a vector.) of the stocks you want to include called `myStocks`

Then you can subset by saying:

```
sp500dataonly<- t[t$SYMBOL %in% myStocks,]
```

example:

```
mySpecies <-c("versicolor","virginica" )

iris[iris$Species %in% mySpecies,]
```

Will give the subset we are after.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted!