# Subset Dataframe using list of character elements

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match, subset

I have a dataframe k with a column d full of character elements and a list d' containing the names that I'm interested in.

From what I found, this seemed to be simple - [How to subset dataframe using string values from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635085/how-to-subset-dataframe-using-string-values-from-a-list)

The answer ought to be:

```
k <- k[k$d %in% d']
```

The result of which is:

```
A tibble: 0 × 39
... with 39 variables: ... d < chr > ...
```

I'm thinking there's something going wrong in the data, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.

Comment: `k$d %in% unlist(d')` will work

Comment: Perfect!  Could you explain why it worked/what the difference is?

Comment: `unlist` turns the list into a vector which is what `%in%` expects to have

Comment: So `%in%` will not match values in lists?  Only vectors?

Comment: How on earth is `d'` a valid object name?

Comment: @thelatemail I was just shortening the actual object names and because they were similar d' (prime) seemed appropriate

Comment: no no! %in% will work with `lists`, but that depends on whether you `lists` inside `lists` too. I dont think those cases work

Comment: So I am a little confused, %in% expects to have a vector, but will work with lists, so why did this particular case not work until the list became a vector?