# subset data with conditions over different rows

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to subset data according to conditions in different rows. 
In other words, I'd like to subset `customers` who visit store `A` and store `B`.

Here is an example:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(cust_id=sample(c(1:3),5,replace = TRUE), 
                   store=sample(LETTERS[1:2],5,replace = TRUE))

> dfrm
     cust_id store
>>       3     B
>>       3     A
>>       1     B
>>       1     B
>>       2     B
```

and I'd like to get a subset of `cust_id` = 3, because he visit `A` and `B`.

**data**

```
dfrm <-
structure(list(cust_id = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 2), store = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cust_id", "store"),
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a data frame based on values in a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612235/select-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-values-in-a-vector)

Comment: Sraffa, I've looked over the question you linked to, and I don't think it answers my problem (maybe I missed something). @Lamia already solved my problem, but TKS anyway.

Comment: I added a reproducible version of your data set. Your's is not reproducible because you did not include `set.seed`.

Comment: Suppose `cust_id` has two `B`-values and one `A`-value. Which values do you then want to keep?

Comment: A base R solution to keep all observations of customers who visit all stores is `dfrm[as.logical(ave(as.character(dfrm$store), dfrm$cust_id, FUN=function(x) all(unique(as.character(dfrm$store)) %in% x))), ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package,
you could do:

```
dfrm %>% group_by(cust_id) %>% filter(n_distinct(store,na.rm=T)==2)
```

Which returns the customers that visit two different stores:

```
cust_id  store
    <dbl> <fctr>
1       3      B
2       3      A
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here are also two `data.table` solutions:

The first one returns *all rows* of `dfrm` of all customers *who visited **exactly two** different stores*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfrm)[, .SD[uniqueN(store) == 2L], by = cust_id]
#   cust_id store
#1:       3     B
#2:       3     A
```

This is what also the [`dplyr` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43877747/3817004) does but about 25% faster for a data set of 80 k rows.

The second one returns *all rows* of `dfrm` of all customers *who visited **the maximum number** of different stores* (which is also 2 in the given toy data sample):

```
setDT(dfrm)[, .SD[uniqueN(store) == uniqueN(dfrm[["store"]])], by = cust_id]
#   cust_id store
#1:       3     B
#2:       3     A
```

This is what also the [base R solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877609/subset-data-with-conditions-over-different-rows#comment74790901_43877609) does but about 15 times faster for a data set of 80 k rows.