# Change many values with specific

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
data.frame(text1 = c("Amazon", "Google", "other"))
```

Add I would like to replace whatever is in the list with a specific value

```
mylist <- c("Amazon", "Google")
```

replace what is in the mylist with stock value

Expected output:

```
data.frame(text1 = c("stock", "stock", "other"))
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/11612235/680068

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do direct assignment :

```
df$text1[df$text1 %in% mylist] <- 'stock'
df
#  text1
#1 stock
#2 stock
#3 other
```

Or use `replace`

```
df$text1 <- replace(df$text1, df$text1 %in% mylist, 'stock')
```

**data**

Read the data as characters :

```
df <- data.frame(text1 = c("Amazon", "Google", "other"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use ifelse() and get a data frame directly

```
a <- data.frame(text1=ifelse(ls$text1 %in% mylist,"stock",as.character(ls$text1)))
a
  text1
1 stock
2 stock
3 other
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution using `gsub`

```
df$text1<- gsub(paste0(paste0("\\b",mylist,"\\b"),collapse = "|"),"stock",df$text1)
```

such that

```
> df
  text1
1 stock
2 stock
3 other
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(text1 = c("Amazon", "Google", "other"))

mylist <- c("Amazon", "Google")
```

Comment: Wouldn't go with regex here, because of partial match, try this data: `df <- data.frame(text1 = c("Amazon", "Amazona", "Google", "other"))`

Comment: @zx8754 thanks for reminder, now I have updated my solution